# Multiple class instantiation or change public property in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oop

I need to access my business layer object 4 times with different constructor.

Specifically I need to access 4 different back end systems through my separate Data Access Layer

What should i do:

1) Instantiate 4 separate objects with different constructor?

2) Instantiate one object and change the public property every time?

As i am now in my HomeController i have the following:

```
var obj = new BarcodeBLL(new ERPConfig
{
    AS400ControlLibrary = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ControlLibrary"],
    AS400Library = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataLibrary"],
    ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AS400"].ConnectionString
});
```

To me it would seem obvious to follow #2 but i would like to know if i am correct and why

Comment: What do you mean by "...and change the public property every time"?

Comment: Since the only thing that will allow me to get to the correct data layer is the connection-string,  i mean to somehow be able to change the connection-string and allow the business layer to reach the correct server.

Comment: So, you are saying that you have 4 identical systems that you can reach via different connection strings?

Comment: Yes, i have 4 AS400 systems (non-unicode) that i can reach by different connectionstrings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 4 identical systems, it would seem logical to have a single class representing such systems. When you need access to one of these systems, you instantiate this type, passing the correct connection string to the constructor.

You may want to hide the details of which connection string is actually being used behind a factory or in the configuration of a DI container.

Comment: My need is to be able to run the same DAL method 4 times in a row. Should i have one object or 4?

Comment: You should probably have 4 objects. If you had only one object, what exactly would that object represent? Would it violate the single responsibility principle (it might or it might not, depending on how the 4 systems change)? On the other hand, if you are just calling this one method, you might want to have a single (possibly) static method that you pass the connection string along with the rest of the required arguments. It is really hard to say in which direction you should go without knowing more about your setup.

Comment: The 4 systems are identical and they have same change management routine. Its not one method that i have to call, there are quite a few. I think 4 objects are the way to go, i would want to know how expensive this is, resource-wise

Comment: Unless you do it in a tight loop, the cost of instantiating 4 simple objects and looking up a bit of information in web.config is negligible. If you do all sorts of expensive work in the type's constructor, it is of course a different matter.